# Help with installing ECL (Embeddable Common Lisp) via mingw32 or mingw-64 on Win7-64

Tags: windows-7, lisp, mingw, common-lisp, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to compile [ECL 10.4.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecls/files/ecls/10.4/ecl-10.4.1.tar.gz/download) on my Win7 64-bit box, but am having issues.

I've attempted the build with both [mingw32/MSYS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20100909/mingw-get-inst-20100909.exe/download) and [mingw-w64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/sezero_4.5_20101002/mingw-w64-bin_x86_64-mingw_20101002_4.5_sezero.zip/download)/[MSYS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/MSYS-20100911.zip/download), using the exact packages linked to here.  Both have failed.

With mingw32: ./configure passes, make fails as follows:

```
gcc -DECLDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/ecl-10.4.1\"" -I. -Ic:/my_home/ecl-10.4.1/build -I/c/my_home/ecl-10.4.1/src/c -I../ecl/gc -DECL_API -DECL_NO_LEGACY   -g -O2   -Dmingw32 -c -o main.o tmp.c

In file included from c:/my_home/ecl-10.4.1/src/c/main.d:20:0:
c:/my_home/ecl-10.4.1/build/ecl/ecl.h:71:4: error: #error "The Windows ports cannot be built without threads."
make[2]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/my_home/ecl-10.4.1/build/c'
make[1]: *** [libeclmin.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/my_home/ecl-10.4.1/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

With mingw-w64: ./configure fails as follows:

```
[...]
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking gmp.h usability... no
checking gmp.h presence... no
checking for gmp.h... no
checking gmp/gmp.h usability... no
checking gmp/gmp.h presence... no
checking for gmp/gmp.h... no
configure: error: Can not find GMP header.
```

Does anyone have any advice for either of these?  Or is there another build system I could try?  (Other than Cygwin which I'm avoiding for licensing reasons.)

---

Comment: Advice: read the error messages you posted. If you did, explain how you tried dealing with them (most basic: add --enable-threads to configure and/or install GMP library), and if didn't work how it failed.

Comment: I did read the messages.

1st one: I had tried two different installs of MinGW32.  One was a classic install-one-by-one install of MinGW core, Msys, GCC, w32 support headers, etc.  Two was an auto-install I later noticed on their SF page.  In both cases the error was the same.

I didn't know about --enable-threads; I will try that.

(The 2nd one is obviously not nearly as close along; since I'm on 64-bit I was just curious if someone knew of a missing package or something like that, or if I had to manually compile/install that library (and any others which would show up after installing GMP).)

Comment: --enable-threads seems to have got me 99% of the way.  Probably I can resolve things from here somehow.  I'd love to give you credit for the answer, but I've no way of doing this for a comment...

Comment: You can also get the official Windows build from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecls/files/ It worked out of the box for me in Win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firt, 10.4.1 is really old release. Update to at least `11.1.1`, or, preferably git version.
Then, you need to install mingw32 (preferably using mingw-get) and msys.

After that, you need to install mingw32-gmp-dev package (or manually compile it), boehm-gc-7.2alpha2 and libffi.

Given all that you should start your msys shell and type the following command:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-Ic:/msysdir/local/include -Ic:/msysdir/local/lib/libffi-3.0.9/include" LDFLAGS="-Lc:/msysdir/local/lib" --prefix=c:/opt/ecl --enable-threads --with-system-gmp -enable-boehm=system && make 2>&1 | tee -a build.log
```

This will build 32 bit version. As for m64 version, you will firs need to build all ECL dependencies as 64 bit. I havent tried that.

Also, you might be able to use gmp and gc included with ECL instead of system ones. I don't do that since ECL build takes much more time that way.

Comment: This question was from 4 months ago; 10.4.1 was the latest release at that time as far as I know ;)

That being said, I will try what you said here.  It'd be excellent to get this working.

Comment: Honestly, I solved this by referring to [this link](http://www.mail-archive.com/ecls-list@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00212.html).  I tweaked the procedure a bit, but I was able to get it installed.  (32-bit version)

I think I was getting blocked based off of using the 7.0 gc instead of one of the 7.2 alphas.  I think if I would have followed your procedure to the letter, it would have got me there as well.

Thanks for the help and the nudge to get this done =)

Comment: @Voltaire: These steps don't include libffi installation. You'll need libffi since it is the only way to get CFFI working in newer versions.

Comment: Wasn't going to worry about FFI, but you pushed me.  In the end, I wrote a full automated installation procedure and pushed it to [github](https://github.com/Vultaire/mingw32_install_ecl.sh).  Maybe it'll help others in the future.  (Requires wget (from gnuwin32) in the PATH for downloading tarballs.)

Comment: Great. It would be good if you could post this script to some more visible space. You could post it to ecl mailing list and it might even be linked from ECL documentation. This (mingw32 build problems) is the question that comes up very often.

Comment: My case was similar in that the usability check on gmp failed. I was working with Ubuntu 14.04 and `libgmp10 2:5.1.3` and trying to install a new isl library version. Problem solved by installing `libgmp-dev`