# Embeddable Common Lisp (ECL) nmake error on Win7-64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64, nmake, ecl

I am trying to install nmake on my windows 7 64-bit version, however, I am getting the following error.

[image]

I downloaded ECL source code from the following link: [ECL Gitlab Repository](https://gitlab.com/embeddable-common-lisp/ecl)

Afterwards, I used a visual studio tool named "Visual Studio 2008 x64 Command Prompt" as per the instructions provided in the "INSTALL" file of the downloaded source code. I made a change in the makefile of the msvc folder with the following: "ECL_WIN64 = 1" and then I ran command "nmake" from the tool which resulted in the error shown above.

I have come across another similar question on SO which is: [Help with installing ECL (Embeddable Common Lisp) via mingw32 or mingw-64 on Win7-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848724/help-with-installing-ecl-embeddable-common-lisp-via-mingw32-or-mingw-64-on-win), however I am not sure which answer can assist me as I am trying to install with Windows with Visual Studio C++ 2008.

Also to point out that "nmake install" is also not working as it tries to copy some files which do not exist in the "package" folder.

I am specifically looking for correct steps to install and build ECL on Win7-x64

Your help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Neel.

UPDATE: I assume the issue lies in it being compiling as C++ rather than C?